# Can AppMaker be used with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, google-app-maker

I understand AppMaker can be used with PostgreSQL and MySQL but the documentation says you can use your own data source. This is a bit ambiguous and I am trying to find out specifically if I can use an existing SQL Server database. I've spoken with Google's support team but they were unable to answer and directed me to ask a question here. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: This page https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/external-data-options says it supports JDBC and REST. You can get a JDBC driver for SQL Server and try that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Next time you reach out the G Suite Support team, ask for the API team. They should be able to assist you on a best effort basis.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is yes but Cloud SQL is easier and works better.

Long answer:

App Maker does support SQL using REST and JDBC **however** it is much harder than using their own CloudSQL model. some code for JDBC from when i last used it:

```
function get_data() {
  var queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM users'; //SQL query
  var calcRecords = []; //empty array to put records into
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd); //connect to database
  var statement = connection.prepareStatement(queryStr); //prepared statement
  var results = statement.executeQuery(); //execute prepared query
  try {
    while (results.next()) {
      var calcRecord = app.models.test.newRecord();
      calcRecord.id = results.getInt(1); //data source test row id
      calcRecord.user = results.getString(2); //data source test row user
      calcRecord.passwd = results.getString(3); //data source test row passwd
      calcRecords.push(calcRecord); //append to 2D array
    }
    results.close(); //close the results
    statement.close(); //close the connection
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('SQL query failed: ' + err);
  }
  return calcRecords;
}
```

The equivalent Google Cloud SQL:

```
function get_users(){
  var ds=app.datasource.Users.Items;
  var data = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < Items.length; i++){
    tmp = [];
    tmp.push(Items[i].id); //the id
    tmp.push(Items[i].user); //the username
    tmp.push(Items[i].password); //the password
    data.push(tmp); //push to create 2D array
  }
  return data;
}
```

Doing query is a little harder and requires server code (so async callbacks), but populating Widgets like dropdown and implementing tables is a lot easier, usually requiring a couple of clicks rather than a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand it's better to use their own service but I have an existing db and migrating it would be a mammoth task. I was just looking for POC at the moment, possibly Microsoft's Power BI might suit me better but it seems a bit pricey.

Comment: Migrating data is actually quite ease. if you can download you db as a CSV and upload it into Google sheets then you can import that data directly including the column names. Its a bit of a pain updating SQL types but thats as much effort as you will need. I do prefer using custom SQL instances so i understand your mentality in this but it is a lot easier using the Cloud SQL, I started doing a project using custom SQL but had to stop because some features were not supported. If you really do want to use SQL then just use REST as its a little easier to manage than JDBC.

Comment: "Migrating data is actually quite ease. if you can download you db as a CSV"

That's the big 'if' and why I said it'd be a mammoth task. It's a database with millions of records going back twenty years, it will need a more robust import strategy than uploading a file.